# Voltage divider, transistor question

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

can voltage divider from the R2 and R3 be used to drive two transistors simultaneously? I need the LED (with Q1) in this circuit to show the state of transistor Q2, i.e. be able to tell if Q2 is conducting. [image]

Comment: If you want the LED to show if Q3 is conducting, why not just connect the LED to Q3?

Comment: It must be separate, and show the state regardless of the load, i.e. whether the load is connected or not.

Comment: It would be in parallel with the load so it would still work if the load is not present.  But if you have another reason for it to be separate, generally yes you could drive both from the same resistor divider.  You say Q1 is actually NPN though?  Can you correct your drawing?

Comment: Oh sorry, no, I thought you had Q1 on the low side.  Like this it won't work.  The base voltage would not be high enough.

Comment: Ok thanks , do you have any suggestion to make it work?

Comment: ^^^ That's for you to figure out. You can make an assumption or makes calculations and we'll tell you if you're right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2filkwO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I'm still not clear why connecting the LED to Q2 would be a problem.  That's the best way to know for sure Q2 is conducting.

Comment: It can be connected to Q2, it just can't be Q3. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant Q3.  I was trying to make the designators match your drawing but accidentally swapped Q2 and Q3.

Comment: Can zener diode be omitted?

Comment: Why was it added?  What is Vcc and what is the Zener voltage?  Is Vcc 9V and your logic signal 9V also?

Comment: VCC is 9V and zener was 2-3v

Comment: So is the logic signal 0-5V?  Then in that case, yes keep the Zener, and it should probably be 3-4V.  If it's 9V then you wouldn't need it.

Comment: What was the function of zener diode?

Comment: If your CMOS logic is 5V and the PNP is tied to 9V, then even when the logic level is high (5V), the PNP would be turned on - you wouldn't be able to turn it off.  Adding a 4V Zener would allow the emitter to drop to 5V, so a high logic level would not allow any base current and leave the PNP off.  When the logic level drops to 0, the base voltage drops to the emitter voltage - 0.7V, so there would be base current and the PNP turns on.

Comment: Wouldn't the output be around 8-9v(VCC is 9v) when high for CMOS gates?

Comment: It depends on the voltage supplied to the CMOS chip.  If the chip/gate that provides the output is tied to the same Vcc, then yes.  That's not included in your schematic so I couldn't say.

Comment: It is indeed tied to VCC.As you mentioned adding a zener would decrease emitter voltage, and since it's important to transistor be off when logic is high, and only turn on when logic is low,I assume the inclusion of zener makes the system more reliable against slight variation in voltage?

Comment: No.  If the gate is working properly, the output will be very close to Vcc when high.  The transistor will stay off.  The voltage would need to be around 0.6V below Vcc to get out of the cut-off region.  The Zener is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

No, that won't work. By adding Q1 you have dragged up the R2/R3 node to 0.7 volts below Vcc. The base-emitter junction of the BJT is a forward biased diode and it will restrict the voltage to about 0.7 volts.

On the other hand this forward biased diode is fighting two forward biased diodes inside Q3. You will have the Vcc rail dragged down to about 2 or 3 volts and, if that rail can supply enough current you will destroy either Q1 or Q3.

Comment: Would that work if Q1 is driven directly from logic gate?

Comment: It needs to have a base resistor in series if driving from a logic gate, probably 10 kohm would do it.

Comment: Also, why have you altered the schematic - this new one won't work either but for different reasons. If you ask a question and someone points out (in a stupid comment) that something is wrong, don't immediately change it and make my answer look stupid.

Comment: > Would that work ... NO. that circuit will burn up once powered on.

Comment: @dannyf who are you addressing this comment to - please use the @"username" identity to signify the recipient.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could suggest a alternative that works.

Comment: @Baphomet Your circuits are in a mess. I'm working to the original circuit and I suggest you return to that and fully explain what you want. If you are addressing this comment to someone else then use @"username".

Comment: @Andyaka The circuit was intended to receive a low from a CMOS logic gate (9v) and drive a darlington (for load) and simultaneously turn on a LED. Load and LED are separate, preferably by using two separate transistors.

Comment: @Andyaka, why was my comment stupid?  The original question noted that the transistor was wrong in the schematic.  Maybe you missed that.

Comment: @AngeloQ yes I take that back now that I've seen it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> I need the LED (with Q1) in this circuit to show the state of transistor Q2

No. the voltage across R3 is clamped to 1.4v (by the darlington), insufficient to turn on Q1/LED1.

put a resistor in Q3's base.